# how to apply function to a list element within a list of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have a list of lists. Here is an example of 2 of the lists inside a list:

```
global_tp_old = [[2, 1, 0.8333595991134644],[2, 1, 0.8530714511871338]]
```

I want to access a dataframe index where the index is specified in the first element of the above list in a list. At the moment I have tried:

```
global_tp_new = []
for element in global_tp_old:
   element[:][0] = df_unique[element[:][0]]
   global_tp_new.append(element)
```

where `df_unique`  is a pandas dataframe produced like this:

```
['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png']
```

I'm trying to match the first element from the list defined above to the number in `df_unique`.

I should get:

```
'img3.png'
```

as it's the 3rd element (0 indexing)

However, I get the incorrect output where it essentially returns the first element every time. It's probably obvious but what do I do to fix this?

Comment: `df_unique` is not a function.  It is a pandas dataframe.  You don't have a list of lists.  You have a pandas dataframe.  Does your dataframe contain embedded lists?  Can you print `df_unique` to show us what it really is?  A dataframe that consists of lists of lists is not very useful.  You may need to create your data in a different way.

Comment: d'oh of course! my bad!, it's a dataframe where I'm trying to match the id of the first element in my list defined above, basically trying to retrieve the first element from the dataframe

Comment: There's just not enough info.  Is that 2x3 array up top in `global_tp_old`?  Is it `df_unique`? Try to make up a complete runnable example that we can cut-and-paste and run on our own.

Comment: Please see my edits above. Hopefully it's clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that your `element` array is actually a reference into the original list.  If you modify the list, you'll modify `global_tp_old` as well.

Something like this, although you may need to change the dataframe indexing depending on whether you're looking for rows or columns.

```
global_tp_old = [[2, 1, 0.8333595991134644],[2, 1, 0.8530714511871338]]

global_tp_new = []
for element in global_tp_old:
   element = [df_unique.iloc[element[0]]] + element[1:]
   global_tp_new.append(element)
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension might be useful to apply a function `fun` to the first element of each list in a list of lists (`LoL`).

```
LoL  = [[61, 1, 0.8333595991134644],[44, 1, 0.8530714511871338]]

newL = [fun(l_loc[0]) for l_loc in LoL]
```

No need to use a Pandas DataFrame.